# Mi estructura do-wile no continua su proceso, solo hace 1 y se termina

Tags: java, while

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que mi estructura continue hasta el infinito y se detenga solo cuando se ingrese una hora negativa o un caracter que no se igual a D y M ,hice mi estructura pero ni bien ponga la hora se cierra la ejecucion y me suelta los resultados ,no se cual es mi error  pero espero su ayuda ,porfavor.

aqui les dejo el codigo en java .

```js
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Practica {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        char grado;
        int hora,cdm=0,cdd=0,mhd=-9999,cmm20=0,contador=1;
        do{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"__Datos de docente "+contador+"__");
            grado=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el grado \n"
                    + "D:doctor M:magister").charAt(0);
            hora=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la hora de trabajo asignada"));
            switch(grado){
                case 'D':
                    if(grado=='D'){
                        cdd=cdd+1;
                        contador=contador+1;
            }
                     if(hora>mhd){
                      mhd=hora;
                      }
                      break;
                case 'M':
                      if(grado=='M')
                      cdm=cdm+1;
                       contador=contador+1;
                      
                     }
                     if(hora>20){
                     cmm20=cmm20+1;
                      
                     }
                     break;
    }while(hora<0 ||grado != 'D' && grado != 'M');
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La Cantidad de docentes con el grado de Doctor :"+cdd+
             "\n La Cantidad de docentes con el grado a magister es de :                 "+cdm+
             "\n La mayor cantidad de horas de docentes del grado Doctor es de :"         +mhd+
             "\n La Cantidad de magister con más de 20 horas asignadas es de : "          +cmm20) ;                
    }
            }
```

Comment: ¿Esta bien que la condición sea que lo haga mientras la hora sea menor a cero?

Comment: si la hora es menor a 0 se cancela el proceso

Comment: es que le estás diciendo que lo haga mientras hora sea menor a cero

Comment: Creo que te faltan unas llaves, uno en `if(grado=='M')` y otro antes de `}while(hora<0...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La condición while que le has puesto significa que **repita mientras "hora" sea menor a  cero**...
SI lo que quieres es que se corte cuando ingreses una hora negativa, la condición debería ser **hora >= 0**.

Answer (score 0):

En tu codigo hay algunas observaciones que debes corregir y que te  las comento:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Practica {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        char grado;
        int hora,cdm=0,cdd=0,mhd=-9999,cmm20=0,contador=1;
        do{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"__Datos de docente "+contador+"__");
            grado=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el grado + "D:doctor M:magister").charAt(0);
            hora=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la hora de trabajo asignada"));
           
           
            switch(grado){
               
               case 'D':
           
                  //  if(grado=='D'){ // Siempre  es verdadero por condición del case.
                        cdd=cdd+1;
                        contador=contador+1;
                    //}
                  if(hora>mhd){
                      mhd=hora;
                  }
                  break;
                case 'M':
                  //    if(grado=='M') Siempre es verdadero
                      cdm=cdm+1;
                       contador=contador+1;
                      
                 //)    }
                  if(hora>20){
                     cmm20=cmm20+1;
                      
                  }
                  break;        // Este break sale del do  si no cierras el switch
           } // Cerrar  switch p
    }while(hora<0 ||grado != 'D' && grado != 'M');
    // hacer mientras sea verdadero hora<0 o grado!="D"  y grado != "M"
```

**Observaciones al While**

Cabe  señalar que  el bloque `do`-`while` se ejecutara  mientras que la condición sea **verdadera**.

Analizando la expresión  tenemos:

1. Segun tu enuncioado quieres que solo salga del while cuando hora sea negativa,
   entonces, la condición  hora<0 hace lo contrario  a lo que quieres basta que la hora sea > 0 para que no se  cumpla. Lo que quieres es `hora>=0`.
2. En las condiciones: grado!=D y grado!=M, será verdedero si se cumplen las dos condiciones, sin embargo,
   a grado!=D le antecede un "o" (de hora>=0), por lo tanto, primero resolverá hora>0 o grado!=D,
   supongamos que grado=D,  la condición se vuelve falso porque  grado no es diferente a D es igual a D y por lo tanto, ya rompió la condición y sale del bloque y eso es lo que no quieres que pase. Solo quieres que salga cuando la hora es negativa o grado no sea igual a D y M. Lo anterior debes expresarlo de la  siguiente manera.

```
       while((hora >= 0) && ((grado == 'D') || (grado == 'M')))
```

**NOTA: La condicional fue corregida gracias a las observaciones y correciones de  RubioRic (ver comentarios)**

Tu do-while quedaría:

```
        do{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"__Datos de docente "+contador+"__");
            grado=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el grado + "D:doctor M:magister").charAt(0);
            hora=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la hora de trabajo asignada"));


            switch(grado){

               case 'D':

                        cdd=cdd+1;
                        contador=contador+1;
                  if(hora>mhd){
                      mhd=hora;
                  }
                  break;
                case 'M':
                      cdm=cdm+1;
                       contador=contador+1;

                  if(hora>20){
                     cmm20=cmm20+1;

                  }
                  break;        // Este break sale del do
           } // Cerrar  switch p
    }while((hora >= 0) && ((grado == 'D') || (grado == 'M'))) ;
```

Comment: La condición que apuntas para el while es incorrecta e incluye doble negación. Debería ser ((hora >= 0) && ((grado == 'D') || (grado == 'M')))

Comment: Tu expresión es equivalente a la mia. Es !(A y B) porque si se cumple A y B entonces tienes que negar para salir del While. No es una doble negación porque no estoy haciendo !(!(A y B) en este caso  A y B devuelven V o F. Ni negando A o B, es decir !A o !B. A=(a operador condicional B) el operador puede ser =, <>,  >, < o !=

Comment: No es equivalente porque la tuya se cumple en cuanto la hora es mayor o igual que cero, independientemente del valor de grado. El bucle debe salirse si grado es distinto de D o M. Además incluye una operación lógica extra de negación.

Comment: Perdon, si tienes razón, no se cumple por el OR. Pongo tu condicional. Gracias.

Comment: Gracias y disculpa por objetar. No me percate que estaba antes el OR previo.

Comment: Nada, hombre. Sin problema. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Tanto Juan Carlos Guibovich como G'Kuan ya te han indicado el problema con la condición del do-while pero me gustaría aprovechar para hacerte algunas recomendaciones más.

---

En tu enunciado te han indicado la condición para que el bucle termine - A - pero siempre tienes que tener en cuenta que la condición que tú tienes que poner es la de que el bucle **ejecute una iteración más** - !A -.

Si A es *cuando se ingrese una hora negativa o un caracter que no sea igual a D y M* podemos expresarlo como

```
HORA_NEGATIVA || (GRADO_NO_D && GRADO_NO_M)
```

Que trasladado a código java quedaría

```
(hora < 0) || (grado != 'D' && grado != 'M')
```

Si NEGAMOS esto aplicando las propiedades de la lógica, quedaría

```
(hora >= 0) && (grado == 'D' || grado == 'M)
```

---

Juan Carlos ha comentado en el código unos if redundantes que haces dentro del switch. ¿Porqué ha hecho esto? Porque la estructura switch es equivalente a varios bloques if-else encadenados, es decir

```
if (grado == 'D') {
    // Hacer 1
} else if (grado == 'M') {
    // Hacer 2
} else {
    // Hacer 3
}
```

es equivalente a

```
switch (grado) {
    case 'D':
          // Hacer 1
          break;
    case 'M':
          // Hacer 2
          break;
    default:
          // Hacer 3
          break;
}
```

Dentro del case 'D' no es necesario que vuelvas a comprobar que grado es 'D'. El propio lenguaje java ya se ha asegurado de que si estás ejecutando Hacer 1 es porque grado es 'D'.

Por otro lado si hay una operación que realizas en todos los casos de tu switch, puedes sacarla fuera en lugar de repetirla. El default no lo tenías puesto, pero como no influye en tu algoritmo, lo he puesto para que el ejemplo quede más claro.

```
switch (grado) {
    case 'D':
          contador = contador + 1;
          break;
    case 'M':
          contador = contador + 1;
          break;
    default:
          contador = contador + 1;
          break;
}
```

Aprovechando el operador ++ para simplificar la expresión de incremento, podríamos hacer

```
switch (grado) {
        case 'D':
              break;
        case 'M':
              break;
        default:
              break;
}

contador++;
```

---

Las convenciones java, que son una serie de reglas que siguen los programadores para que su código sea más legible, recomiendan entre otras cosas que las variables se inicialicen cada una en una línea separada.

```
int hora,cdm=0,cdd=0,mhd=-9999,cmm20=0,contador=1;
```

Se recomienda que se escriba

```
int hora;
int cdm = 0;
int cdd = 0;
int mhd = -9999;
int cmm20 = 0;
int contador = 1;
```

---

Hay otra serie de recomendaciones para hacer más legible el código que se conocen como Clean Code (Código Limpio). Dentro de estas recomendaciones hay una que podemos aplicar en tu código y es que **los nombres de las variables sean significativos**, que otro programador que venga después que tú (o tú mismo dentro de unos meses) entienda el significado de las variables lo más rápido posible, qué representa cada una de ellas sin tener que repasar todo tu código. Es decir cdm es correcto, pero si pones contadorMagister se entiende antes que esa variable posiblemente vaya a acumular un conteo de elementos Magister.

---

Y la última recomendación, **declara constantes en tu código para aumentar también la legibilidad y la mantenibilidad**. ¿A qué me refiero con mantenibilidad? Imagina que tu profesor te dice que cambies el número de horas mínimo de 20 a 30. Actualmente en tu código ese 20 solo aparece en un método pero imagina que para calcular el salario del docente también se empleara en otro método distinto. E incluso en un tercer método para calcular las bonificaciones. Supón que con las prisas por entregar el ejercicio se te olvida cambiar el 20 en los métodos 2 y 3.

Si declaras una constante al principio de la clase y referencias esa constante en los tres métodos, solo tendrías que hacer un cambio en lugar de acordarte de hacer los tres.

---

Si aplicamos todo este rollo que te he contado, también conocido en España como turra, tu código podría quedar así

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Practica {
            
    private static final char DOCTOR = 'D';
    private static final char MAGISTER = 'M';
    private static final int MIN_HORAS_GRADO_M = 20;
    
    public static void main(String[]args){
        char grado;
        
        int hora;
        int maximoHorasDoctor = 0;
        int contadorDoctor = 0;
        int contadorMagister = 0;
        int contadorSuperaMinimo = 0;
        int indexDocente = 1;
                
        do {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "__Datos de docente " + indexDocente + "__");
            grado = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el grado \n D:doctor M:magister").charAt(0);
            hora = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la hora de trabajo asignada"));
            
            switch (grado){
                case DOCTOR:
                    contadorDoctor++;
                    
                    if (hora > maximoHorasDoctor){
                        maximoHorasDoctor = hora;
                    }
                    break;
                    
                case MAGISTER:
                    contadorMagister++;
                    
                    if (hora > MIN_HORAS_GRADO_M){
                        contadorSuperaMinimo++;                      
                    }
                    
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            
            indexDocente++;
            
    } while ((hora >= 0) && (grado == DOCTOR || grado == MAGISTER));
        
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La Cantidad de docentes con el grado de Doctor :" + contadorDoctor +
             "\n La Cantidad de docentes con el grado a magister es de :                 " + contadorMagister +
             "\n La mayor cantidad de horas de docentes del grado Doctor es de :"          + maximoHorasDoctor +
             "\n La Cantidad de magister con más de 20 horas asignadas es de : "           + contadorSuperaMinimo) ;                
    }
}
```